# If statement not working: need application to stop flagging text inside script tags

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I am working on an application my team inherited from a developer (a 13 year old application) and I am trying to stop the application from giving error messages for unitalicized variables when those variables appear inside `<script> </script>` tags. I have found some regex solutions that will flag when something is inside of those tags, but it's not working when I run the build for some reason. Can anyone see the problem at a glance? I only added the `If New Regex <script>` line of code.

```
Private Function ReplaceForAnalyzeItalics(ByVal m As Match) As String
    Dim myStr As String = m.Value

    'This ignore articles, the word x-ray, section labels such as (a)-(f)
    If myStr.ToUpper.Contains(" A ") Or myStr.Contains("(A ") Or myStr.Contains(vbLf & "A ") Or myStr.ToUpper.Contains("X-R") Then GoTo ReplaceForAnalyzeItalicsEND
    If New Regex("^[\s\S]\([a-ms]\)", RegexOptions.None).Match(myStr).Success Then GoTo ReplaceForAnalyzeItalicsEND
    If New Regex("^[\s\S]{[lcr]}", RegexOptions.None).Match(myStr).Success Then GoTo ReplaceForAnalyzeItalicsEND ' Regex <pre:watex> array alignment pattern
    **If New Regex("^\<script[\s\S]*\>[\s\S]*<\/script\>", RegexOptions.None).Match(myStr).Success Then GoTo ReplaceForAnalyzeItalicsEND**


    'Don't remember what this was rejecting
    If myStr(3) = "." Then
        If myStr(1) = "." Then GoTo ReplaceForAnalyzeItalicsEND
        If Char.IsLetter(myStr(4)) Then GoTo ReplaceForAnalyzeItalicsEND
    End If

    If myStr(2).ToString.IndexOfAny("msghjkuTCAVWJKNHLFOHC".ToCharArray) = 0 Then
        If myStr.StartsWith("/ ") Or myStr(1) = "/" Then GoTo ReplaceForAnalyzeItalicsEND 'This rejects units such as m/s
        If myStr.EndsWith("/ ") Or myStr(3) = "/" Then GoTo ReplaceForAnalyzeItalicsEND 'This rejects units such as m/s
        If myStr(1) = ">" Or myStr(1) = ")" Then GoTo ReplaceForAnalyzeItalicsEND 'This rejects units following number or probable eqn tag or vector or <s:degree>
        If (myStr(1) = " " Or myStr(1) = "-") And (Char.IsDigit(myStr(0)) Or myStr(0) = ">" Or myStr(0) = ")") Then GoTo ReplaceForAnalyzeItalicsEND 'This rejects units following number or probable eqn tag or vector
    End If
    If (Char.IsDigit(myStr(0)) Or Char.IsDigit(myStr(1))) And (myStr(2) = "X" Or myStr(2) = "x") And (myStr(4) = "1" Or (myStr(3) = "1" And myStr(4) = "0")) Then GoTo ReplaceForAnalyzeItalicsEND 'This rejects scientific notation
    If myStr.StartsWith("p>") Then GoTo ReplaceForAnalyzeItalicsEND 'This rejects isotopes of elements
    If myStr(2).ToString.IndexOfAny("ehps".ToCharArray) = 0 And myStr(3) = ":" And (myStr(1) = "<" Or myStr(1) = "/") Then GoTo ReplaceForAnalyzeItalicsEND 'This rejects the namespaces
    If myStr(1) = "_" Or myStr(3) = "_" Then GoTo ReplaceForAnalyzeItalicsEND 'This rejects symbolic answer prompts describing which variable names to use

    ErrorCheckManager.AddHighlight(myStr(2).ToString, "may need italics", "", m.Index, myStr(2), 117)

ReplaceForAnalyzeItalicsEND:
        Return myStr.Remove(2, 1).Insert(2, "|") 'Replace letter with nonletter so this will not get matched again
    End Function
```

Comment: goto? really???

Comment: The "may need italics" comment is the message the application sends when users are inputting code in <script> tags, and I'm trying to find a way to get it not to do that. You can see that other exceptions are in this code, for example when m/s is a unit, its obviously not a variable and therefore shouldn't be italicized. So they don't want the message for that case.